# creating a choropleth of a non map image dc.js

Tags: json, d3.js, geojson, dc.js, crossfilter

In a dashboard that i'm creating i need to have a schematic anatomical image of the ear with different regions that change color based on the amount of patients with infections in that reason. Basically think of the choropleth of us states as shown here http://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/vc/ but instead of a map of the US it would be a schematic picture of the ear and instead of states it would be specific regions of the ear. How would i go about getting the image in a geojson format?

Comment: Do you have an image you are currently working with?  What format is it?  Cool project, btw.

Comment: @Mark http://postimg.org/image/oce1lxgmd/ this is the image but then without the colors. the colors are just there to specify the regions. I assume i need some sort of software to create my own json for this polygon

Comment: Any ideas? was thinking myself of maybe first coverting the image to svg. And then i believe there is software to turn svg paths into JSON polygons

Comment: If you can convert your image to svg, each piece of the drawing will be a path.  Assign each path a unique id and you can color them based on that.  No need for geojson or polygons.

Comment: @Mark but will this work will dc.js? because i need the filtering to be linked with the rest of the dashboard

Comment: I think the easiest thing to do here is to produce your own geojson file (the format is not complicated) and then specify identity for the projection so that pixel coordinates get mapped to pixel coordinates. I don't have an example though. :-/

Comment: @Gordon any tips/guides on doing this

Comment: Nope, as I said I don't have any examples and don't know anyone who has done this. So unfortunately I'm just speculating based on my knowledge of the code. :-/

Comment: Okay thanks i will see if i can get it done by hand.  Last question any tool i can use to view a geojson as ghe image so testing is easier